# Copying data from one sheet to another with VBA loops

Tags: database, vba, loops, for-loop

I am a newbie to the VBA programming, so I need your help here. I have to create a macro that copies data from one sheet to another. So what I've done is recording a macro (using macro recorder) to the steps that I have to copy/paste. Now i have to create a loop to do it for all the information that I need.

Here are screenshots of the sheet that contains the data:

[image: Monthly Report Image]

Here is screenshot of the sheet that the data should be pasted:

[image: Desired Result Image]

So lets talk about the data, that my report contains. I have a monthly report for the countries, that my company serves. On every day of the month I have some forecast, that should be uploaded to our database.

Here is the code that i already have:

```
Sub manual_upload()

    Sheets("Forecast").Select

    Range("G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Upload").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True


    Sheets("Forecast").Select
    'ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    'ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1

    Range("C2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Upload").Select

    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.FillDown

    'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B31")
    'Range("B2:B31").Select

    Sheets("Forecast").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Upload").Select

    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("b2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.FillDown

    'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C31")
    'Range("C2:C31").Select

    Sheets("Forecast").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Upload").Select

    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("c2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.FillDown

    'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D31")
    'Range("D2:D31").Select

    Range("E2").Select
    Sheets("Forecast").Select
    Range("G2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Upload").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("Forecast").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Upload").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F31")
    Range("F2:F31").Select

    'next i
End Sub
```

I dont know how to start the loop. Which data should be added like a various and etc. 
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Depending on how many columns across the forecasts are, i would suggest thinking about using Powerquery. The basic steps are: Set your source data, as in your posted image 1, as a table, have powerquery pick that table up (query from table), then rename the columns you want to keep, remove those you don't want, and highlight all the date columns and do unpivot columns from transform tab (or right click). Then close and load to sheet.

Comment: Did your explanation cut off? You do not explain how fields are filled in desired result. What is *Dashboard*, *Forecast*? Other than that this looks like a melt process. Any dataset holding program/language like Python pandas/R/SAS can reshape accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guide to performing these steps without VBA if data is all in one sheet (you can use merge of multiple queries with same structure if data is in different sheets):

1) Select your data and set up as a table by pressing Control + T. :
[image: Table]

2) Import your data using powerquery (excel 2016 from table option is in Data tab, in earlier versions you need to install the powerquery add in and use the power tab). A window will appear with your table data in. You will then work with this view of your data.

[image: Adding to powerquery from table]

3) Remove unwanted columns by highlighting and then right click remove

[image: Remove columns]

4) Select the Date columns and unpivot. You can select the first date column then hold shift and select last date column to highlight all)

[image: Unpivot date columns]

5) Double click in column headers to rename e.g. Attribute -> Date, Value -> Forecast, Name in DB -> Country

[image: Renaming columns]

6) Check data types are correct

[image: Setting column data types]

7) Reorder your columns to match desired output by dragging them to re-arrange

[image: Re-arrange column order]

8) Finally close and load to your worksheet

[image: Close and load]

9) View result

[image: Result]

10) You can add data to your source table then click refresh on the query to update everything. Apologies different table in image as this image is a later edit in response to a question. When selecting a cell in your results table the query window will appear and you will see the name of your query and a green refresh arrow. Click on this to update when source data has changed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help, but I need to create a macro, because I will change this data on a monthly base. So that mean that I will have months with lower days.

Comment: The table will automatically update and the query created has a little green arrow. When you have new data in your source table, you click on the arrow and everything is updated. Y

Comment: Thank you, but lets say my BOSS wants a macro :D:D:D